# How can I change my default/main calendar in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Every time someone sends me an invitation it goes to my default (poorly-named) Google Calendar. I can't delete that calendar because it's my default. I can't make events go to my other calendars because they go to this default calendar.

How can I make another calendar the default?

Comment: Here are some detailed instructions: http://tips-a-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-change-default-google-calendar.html

Comment: I have reopened the discussion at google calendar forum to suggest the feature. Every other discussion was closed due to inactivity. Please take a moment to keep this thread active so that we get some action.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/calendar/desktop-computer/mac/suggest-new-feature/user-interface-and-views/QC677YHArmE

Answer (score 14):

So, there's no way for you to change which of your calendars is the default. However, a fairly simple workaround is to import a new calendar that has all of the events from your default calendar. And then remove all the events from the default. So, that way, when you get invites, you can name the default calendar your Invites or Events or something.

To do this:

1. Go to your default calendar's settings
2. Click the ICAL option for the Private Address and save the .ics file to your computer
3. Create a new calendar
4. Click the Add dropdown and select Import Calendar
5. Select the .ics file you just saved, and import it to the new calendar you just created

Voila! Now you have a new calendar with the original events and you can delete all the things off your default and let it only have the invitation events.

Answer (score 4):

You can't force Google Calendar to send invites to your other calendars, but you can easily change the name of the poorly-named default calendar. Go to **Settings** > **Calendars** and by clicking on it you can change bunch of stuff there.

Comment: Indeed. I just changed the name of my default calendar.

Comment: This is a more reliable solution, than the export->import ICS solution.  Simple, yet performs the result